# ifconfig not included in Ubuntu 20.04 / Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, ifconfig, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I have a bash script that does, among other things, `MY_IP="$(ifconfig en0 inet)"` but apparently Ubuntu 20.04 / Hyper-V / WSL2 doesn't have ifconfig.

Is there a way to install it or do I need to rewrite my scripts to work around it? If so what would be a good way to work around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-missing-ifconfig-command-on-debian-linux - ipconfig has been deprecated (meaning you ideally should rewrite your scripts to use IP).

That said you can "apt install net-tools" to install the old ifconfig packages, and it should "play nice".